# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o45.load. : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/StreamWriteSupport

Tags: docker, pyspark, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Kafka and pyspark. What I'm trying to do is publish some data into the Kafka and then using the pyspark-notebook to reach those data for further processing. I'm using Kafka and pyspark-notebook on docker and my spark version there is 2.4.4. to set up the environment and reaching data I'm running the following code:

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars dependency/elasticsearch-hadoop-7.6.0.jar  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.4.4,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.4 pyspark-shell'

spark = SparkSession.builder \
.master("local[*]") \
.appName("reactor_ds_data_streaming") \
.config("es.nodes", "http://10.29.18.124") \
.config("es.port","9200") \
.getOrCreate()

kafka_msg = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "10.29.18.124:9092") \
        .option("subscribe", "reactor-raw") \
        .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
        .option("failOnDataLoss", "False") \
        .load()
```

When I run the final step (kafka_msg) I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o45.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/StreamWriteSupport
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1209)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1220)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1384)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:43)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:255)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl$(TraversableLike.scala:249)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filterImpl(Traversable.scala:108)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter(TraversableLike.scala:347)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter$(TraversableLike.scala:347)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:649)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:194)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.StreamWriteSupport
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 43 more
```

I do not know what is the problem exactly and I really appreciat if someone can help me to understand what I should fix to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: Where are your jars placed?Please make sure it's present in the host from where you are submitting the application.I see you are using Pyspark shell and by default, it uses deploy mode as client

Comment: Since you're using Structured Streaming, you don't need streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.4.4 but do you really need Spark? There's native Python libraries for Kafka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what was the problem. I need to add "kafka-client" jar file as well in my packages directory.